# $l$-regular bipartition

Tags: integer-partitions

I know about $l$-regular partition. Now I came across $l$-regular bipartition/tripartition. But how are former and latter different. Where former ensures that each part in the partition is not divisible by $l$, if the latter does the same, how are they both different? This question is in the context of curiosity while studying a paper on congruences of partitions. Where could this be possibly useful?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definitions that I’ve seen, an $\ell$-regular bipartition of $n$ is an ordered pair $\langle\lambda_1,\lambda_2\rangle$ of $\ell$-regular partitions such that the sum of all of the parts of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is $n$. Thus,

$$\big\langle\langle 4,2,1\rangle,\langle 5,5\rangle\big\rangle$$

is a $3$-regular bipartition of $17$.

Presumably an $\ell$-regular tripartition of $n$ is an ordered triple $\langle\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\rangle$ of $\ell$-regular partitions such that the sum of all of the parts of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ is $n$.

**Added in response to comment:** There is exactly one partition of $17$ with parts $5,5,4,2$, and $1$: $\langle 5,5,4,2,1\rangle$. But these five parts can be split between two partitions in several different ways, so there are several bipartitions of $17$ with these five parts:

$$\begin{align*}
&\big\langle\langle 5,4,2,1\rangle,\langle 5\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 5\rangle,\langle 5,4,2,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,2,1\rangle,\langle 4\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 4\rangle,\langle 5,5,2,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,4,1\rangle,\langle 2\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 2\rangle,\langle 5,5,4,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,4,2\rangle,\langle 1\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 1\rangle,\langle 5,5,4,2\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 4,2,1\rangle,\langle 5,5\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 5,5\rangle,\langle 4,2,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,4\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 5,5,4\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,2\rangle,\langle 4,1\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 4,1\rangle,\langle 5,5,2\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,5,1\rangle,\langle 4,2\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 4,2\rangle,\langle 5,5,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,4,2\rangle,\langle 5,1\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 5,1\rangle,\langle 5,4,2\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,4,1\rangle,\langle 5,2\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 5,2\rangle,\langle 5,4,1\rangle\big\rangle;\\
&\big\langle\langle 5,2,1\rangle,\langle 5,4\rangle\big\rangle;\big\langle\langle 5,4\rangle,\langle 5,2,1\rangle\big\rangle\,.
\end{align*}$$

That’s $22$ bipartitions with the same five parts, assuming that I didn’t miss any.

Comment: Yeah, this thing is clear @Brian. But I don’t understand the difference in the number of such partitions vs bipartitions for a given number n.

Comment: @user511110: I’ve expanded my answer to deal with what I think you’re asking here.

Comment: That helps! Except that, can’t we partition 17 as $\big\langle\phi,\langle 5,5,4,2,1 \rangle\big\rangle$, where $\phi$ is a null set?

Comment: With null set I meant null partition

Comment: @user511110: That would depend on whether partitions of $0$ are allowed, and I simply don't know whether they are permitted in this context.